# Order items in a Multi Values Listview in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

I'm looking to some way for sort my items inside my listview. Which is a multi values Listview with 3 items for each row. I use a Custom ListViewAdapter to achieve this, but they are sorted in order of introduction inside the ArraysList. Something like:

```
1-2-3-4-5-6....
```

I want to inverse this order, having in top of my Listview the last item introduced:

```
6-5-4-3-2-1....
```

Here is my Custom ListViewAdapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView number;
    TextView elapsedTime;
    TextView totalTime;
}

public static final String FIRST_COLUMN="First";
public static final String SECOND_COLUMN="Second";
public static final String THIRD_COLUMN="Third";

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;

public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    super();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        viewHolder.elapsedTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.elapsed_time);
        viewHolder.totalTime =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total_time);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    viewHolder.number.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    viewHolder.elapsedTime.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    viewHolder.totalTime.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
}
}
```

And here is how I call it in my activity:

```
 //ListView Adapter
    mListviewLayout = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.listview_times_layout);

    mTimesListview = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.times_listview);
    mTimesArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    mListViewAdapter= new ListViewAdapter(mActivity, mTimesArrayList);
    mTimesListview.setAdapter(mListViewAdapter);
```

Finally, here is how I introduce items inside the Hashmap:

```
 btnNextCicle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isTimerPaused()) {
                onTimerStop();
            } else {
                mListviewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCiclesCounter++;
                HashMap<String, String> newEntry = new HashMap<String, String>();
                newEntry.put(ListViewAdapter.FIRST_COLUMN, "#" + mCiclesCounter);
                newEntry.put(ListViewAdapter.SECOND_COLUMN, Util.getTimeForTimer(mElapsedCicleTime));
                newEntry.put(ListViewAdapter.THIRD_COLUMN, Util.getTimeForTimer(mTimeInMilliseconds));
                mCicleStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                mTimesArrayList.add(newEntry);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `HashMap<String, Sting>` and make it implements `Comparable`. Then you can use `Arrays.sort(yourComparable)` to sort the array the way you want.